# Aps.net core Razor page [FromBody] Ajax post Model always is null

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-core, razor-pages

In Asp.Net core I have a razor page and I want to send a Ajax post to a Post method but always I get null model.here is my simplify question.

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnPost([FromBody]A A)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

and this is my model:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptOut)]
public class A
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string CityId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string Infected { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string Susceptible { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string Recovered { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string CityName { get; set; }
}
```

This is my Ajax request:

```
function f(event) {
    var token = $("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val();
    var c = {};
        c["Id"] = "1";
        c["CityId"] = "2";
        c["Infected"] = "3";
        c["Susceptible"] = "4";
        c["Recovered"] = "5";
        c["CityName"]=""
    $.ajax({
        url: "./DynamicEpidemic",
        type: "post",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        headers:
{
    "RequestVerificationToken": token
        },
        data: { A: JSON.stringify(c)},
        success: function () {
            alert("OK");
        }
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(c));

}
```

and sent json object is like this:

`{"Id":"1","CityId":"2","Infected":"3","Susceptible":"4","Recovered":"5","CityName":""}`

but my model is always null.ModelState error is

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: A. Path '', line 0, position 0.

Comment: Have you tried `data: JSON.stringify(c)`?

Comment: Hey man you're great you release my mind after tow days.Thank you so much.It works

Comment: Ok I will add an answer for helping other people  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing to `data: JSON.stringify(c)`.